# tmux transpose / rearrange panes?

Tags: unix, tmux, panes

I have a layout right now that looks like

```
 1
***
 2
***
 3
```

and I want it to look like

```
 1
***
 3
***
 2
```

I know the command `C-b C-o` cycles their positions, but it's not possible to write a transposition as a product of cycles, mathematically speaking. I also know there are commands to reorder *windows* but I am interested in panes. Can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 41):

From the middle pane use <kbd>Prefix</kbd><kbd>}</kbd>, or from the bottom pane use <kbd>Prefix</kbd><kbd>{</kbd>. The default bindings for these keys are `swap-pane -D` and `swap-pane -U`.

Comment: This will re-order the contents of the panes, but the indices of the panes will stay the same.  I know this because I am looking at re-ordering the pane indices, but can only re-order their contents, sadly.

Answer (score 5):

In my tmux the <kbd>Prefix</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> allowed me to move the pane around to a different index.